# AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.bigquery._helpers' has no attribute 'PYARROW_VERSIONS'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, error-handling, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, pyarrow

While running the below import command in GCP jupyterlab getting an error:

**Code:**

```
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery

import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
```

Error:

> ---
>
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> /tmp/ipykernel_5450/3407211047.py in 
> 1 from google.cloud import storage
> 2 from google.cloud import bigquery
> 3
> 4 import pandas as pd
> 5 from sklearn import datasets
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/**init**.py in 
> 33 **version** = bigquery_version.**version**
> 34
> 35 from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client
> 36 from google.cloud.bigquery.dataset import AccessEntry
> 37 from google.cloud.bigquery.dataset import Dataset
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py in 
> 74
> 75
> 76 from google.cloud.bigquery import _job_helpers
> 77 from google.cloud.bigquery._job_helpers import make_job_id as _make_job_id
> 78 from google.cloud.bigquery._helpers import _get_sub_prop
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_job_helpers.py in 
> 22 from google.api_core import retry as retries
> 23
> 24 from google.cloud.bigquery import job
> 25
> 26 # Avoid circular imports
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/**init**.py in 
> 25 from google.cloud.bigquery.job.base import TransactionInfo
> 26 from google.cloud.bigquery.job.base import UnknownJob
> 27 from google.cloud.bigquery.job.copy_ import CopyJob
> 28 from google.cloud.bigquery.job.copy_ import CopyJobConfig
> 29 from google.cloud.bigquery.job.copy_ import OperationType
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/copy_.py in 
> 19 from google.cloud.bigquery.encryption_configuration import EncryptionConfiguration
> 20 from google.cloud.bigquery import _helpers
> 21 from google.cloud.bigquery.table import TableReference
> 22
> 23 from google.cloud.bigquery.job.base import _AsyncJob
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py in 
> 55 import google.cloud._helpers  # type: ignore
> 56 from google.cloud.bigquery import _helpers
> 57 from google.cloud.bigquery import _pandas_helpers
> 58 from google.cloud.bigquery.exceptions import LegacyBigQueryStorageError
> 59 from google.cloud.bigquery.schema import _build_schema_resource
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py in 
> 49     date_dtype_name = time_dtype_name = ""  # Use '' rather than None because pytype
> 50
> 51 pyarrow = _helpers.PYARROW_VERSIONS.try_import()
> 52
> 53 try:
>
> AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.bigquery._helpers' has no attribute 'PYARROW_VERSIONS'

tried installing pyparrow

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyarrow
```

Tried upgrading bigquery storage

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall google-cloud-bigquery-storage

!pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
!pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
```

Comment: Found the answer, restarting kernel and re-running !pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
!pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, restarting kernel and re-running

```
!pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery
!pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
```

It worked.